# Karma: Cannot read property * of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a service which I would like to test:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  initialAuthStatus = this.authenticationStatus.first();

  constructor(private adalService: AdalService,
              private settingsProvider: SettingsProvider) { }


  public get authenticationStatus(): any {
    return this.adalService.userInfo.authenticationStatus;
  }
}
```

And a test for the service:

```
describe('AuthenticationService', () => {
    let mockAdalService: any;
    let adalService: any;
    let service: any;
    let mockSettingsProvider: any;
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          providers: [
            AuthenticationService, 
            AdalService,
            { provide: SettingsProvider, useClass: MockSettingsProvider },
            { provide: AdalService, useClass: MockAdalService }
          ]
        });

        mockAdalService = new MockAdalService();
        adalService = new AdalService();
        mockSettingsProvider = new MockSettingsProvider();
    });

    it('should be created', inject([AuthenticationService], (service: AuthenticationService) => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

However, the test fails with the following error message:

```
AuthenticationService should be created
TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticationStatus' of undefined
```

It has something to do with the getter of authentication status, but I can't figure out exactly why it fails.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Error comes from this line :   initialAuthStatus = this.authenticationStatus.first(); it's hasn't been initialized at that point

Comment: How can I solve it?

Comment: put it in the constructor or ngOnInit and leave just   initialAuthStatus at the top

Comment: Wow, ok I was really blind. I've put it in ngOnInit now (constructor didn't work), and it works now. Thanks a log :)
Please write a post so that I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the class, in this line, where you declare the class property `initialAuthStatus`:

```
initialAuthStatus = this.authenticationStatus.first();
```

`this.authenticationStatus` hasn't been initialized yet, gives you the error message. 
To make it work, put that line in ngOnInit() method and keep pure declaration part at the top of the class.

```
initialAuthStatus;
...
ngOnInit(){
    this.initialAuthStatus = this.authenticationStatus;
}
...
...
```

Comment: That's the solution! However, it's this.initialAuthStatus in ngOnInit() :)
Thanks for your help :)